# Blazor InputSelect binding value and updating another on select

Tags: c#, blazor

In my InputSelect I need to be able to bind a value and on option select/click update both that value and another.

What my object looks like:

```
public class AccountModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an Office")]
    public Office[] Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Office()
    {
            
    }

    public Office(string _id, string _name)
    {
        Id = _id;
        Name = _name;
    }
}
```

InputSelect:

```
<p class="m-0 form-details-lbl">Office</p>
        <InputSelect class="m-0 form-control edit-active"
                     @bind-Value="Account.Office[0].Id">
            <option selected disabled>Select Office</option>
                    @foreach (Office office in OfficeLoc)
            {
            <option value=@office.Id @onselect="() => Account.Office[0].Name = office.Name">@office.Name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Account.Office" />
```

So that `office[0].Id` is bound to the InputSelect, however on an option select from the list of offices it will update both the id and the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the other answer because seeing where I was wrong might be useful.  When I checked, I realized that events on the `<option>` tag don't fire, including even onclick.

Try something like the following.  You might need to add a using for `System.Linq`.

```
<select name="offices" id="offices" @onchange="SelectOffice">
    <option selected hidden>Select a room</option>
    @foreach (var office in AvailableOffices)
    {
        <option value=@office.ID>@office.Name</option>
    }
</select>

@code{
    Office SelectedOffice {get;set;} // i.e. Account.Office[0]
    List<Office> AvailableOffices {get; set;}

    void SelectOffice(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedOffice = AvailableOffices.Where(ao => ao.ID.ToString() == e.Value.ToString()).First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Account.Office[0] is the same model as your array items, I'd just set the whole object.

```
<option value=@office.Id @onselect="() => Account.Office = office">@office.Name</option>
```

If they are not the same model, I'd use a method:

```
 <option value=@office.Id @onselect="() => SetOffice(office)">@office.Name</option>

@code {
     void SetOffice(Office newOffice){
             Account.Office[0].Id = newOffice.id;
             Account.Office[0].Name = newOffice.Name;
     }
}
```

*Note I'm at work right now, so forgive any typos or inaccuracies.  You might have to tweak it a little, but hopefully the idea is clear enough.*

Comment: Would this involve not using a SelectInput Component? Because the @onselect doesn't get hit I find when using a SelectInput and binding a value to it. Plus office is the same model used in Account.Office[0].

Comment: I've been using almost exclusively vanilla elements, with no ill effect that I can see, except for actual forms where I want a mechanism for validating multiple inputs.